# How do I fix "remote: fatal error in commit_refs" errors trying to push with Git?

Tags: git, github, git-push

When I try to push to `master` branch that is hosted on https://github.com I get:

> remote: fatal error in commit_refs

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is the remote repository hosting/located? Might be that this is corrupt?

Comment: Thank you for helping! The remote is github. Seems it was a local error (none of the others working against the same repo have had this issue).

Comment: This seems to be a recent GitHub issue, see also http://pastebin.com/50BL9YTF  and http://blastedbio.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/sync-github-mirror-with-cron.html also from 20 May 2016.

Comment: This can also occur if GitHub has a service outage

Comment: None of the above solved my issue. However, a good old system restart did.

Comment: It's almost definitely GitHub a service outage.

Comment: same here, it seems to happen once in a while. restarting the system and just trying the next day makes the problem go away for me.

Answer (score 1069):

In my case, GitHub was down by the time I was trying to push.

Just check https://www.githubstatus.com to know about GitHub site status.

When it's up you'll be able to push.

Comment: I waited 10 minutes while https://www.githubstatus.com/ was reporting OK status

Comment: Waiting worked for me, even though everything was shown as online

Comment: I went to githubstatus.com, read "All Systems Operational", and then assumed that wasn't it. 15 minutes later, githubstatus.com showed that GitHub was down.

Answer (score 157):

This fixed it for me:

```
git gc
```

That will start a garbage collection that resolved my error.

Comment: `git gc` didn't solve it for me, but `git fsck` and then `git gc` did it.

Comment: docs: [git fsck](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) and [git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

Comment: This worked for me also.  Good to do some preventative maintenance on a regular basis.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure your repo is online.

I got this error today when attempting to push to github and then couldn't even browse the site without getting their unicorn error message.

Answer (score 5):

Try rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch after pull, e.g.

```
git pull origin master -r
```

then push it again:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Lol i tried that earlier today, and my repository got absolutely empty cuz it didn't want to push it back, luckily I have all my files saved in my code editor and in backup, but yeah apparently github's down...

Answer (score 4):

I raised this with GitHub in relation to http://blastedbio.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/sync-github-mirror-with-cron.html and it turned out to be due to protected branch settings. GitHub have improved the error message:

```
$ git push mirror master
Counting objects: 391, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (391/391), done.
Writing objects: 100% (391/391), 99.28 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 391 (delta 298), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: You're not authorized to push to this branch. Visit https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/ for more information.
To git@github.com:HuttonICS/biopython.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:HuttonICS/biopython.git'
```

If you try again now you ought to get a more constructive error report. In my case I needed to adjust my protected branch settings as per https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/

Comment: In my case the problem was also caused by protected branch settings.

Answer (score 4):

Opening a new terminal and trying worked for me.

Comment: May have just been lucky and done this as github went back up.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, there is now (2019) some rate limit on GitHub that causes this problem for me when mass-pushing tens of huge repositories.
It can also cause "cannot read" problem in random cases.

When **I delay for 30 seconds before each push**, both problems go away and I can continue with hundreds of repos without a glitch (sigh, don't even ask).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I suspect a hung git process was causing the problem; I killed it and retried and the problem went away.

Comment: This was the most similar to my issue - I just needed to close VSCode, which likely had a git process working in the background that was hung for some reason.

Answer (score -3):

Pulling down latest code from the branch solved it for me:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```