# Git failed to push some refs

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push my commits to my github repo. Currently I'm working on a branch (mysql and it worked yesterday. Today I get the following error:

```
Counting objects: 22, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 2.79 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 22 (delta 17), reused 11 (delta 6)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (17/17), completed with 13 local objects.
remote: fatal error in commit_refs
To https://github.com/*********.git
! [remote rejected] mysql -> mysql (failure)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/*********.git'
```

I already tried pulling, even though I'm the only one working on this repo

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341960/how-do-i-fix-remote-fatal-error-in-commit-refs-errors-trying-to-push-with-git

Comment: I tried that and it did not work!

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not something inside Git itself, it's a problem specific to GitHub. You need to ask the GitHub people about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix "remote: fatal error in commit\_refs" errors trying to push with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341960/how-do-i-fix-remote-fatal-error-in-commit-refs-errors-trying-to-push-with-git)