# ! [remote rejected] main -> main (failure) , failed to push some refs, when trying to push to the only branch in a repository

Tags: git, git-push

I'm working on this discord bot, and I only got 1 branch in my repository, ain't needing more. I opened up my command line the way I have been for the past few weeks, and it said something about `git --version` that was wrong but then it bypassed it or something and console started to work. Then I made a few tweaks to an existing file and simply did `git status` to see if it was addable for a commit which it was. Then i did `git add *` which worked, then `git commit -m "fixed negative number error"` and then when I did `git push origin main` which I have been doing for weeks, it said

```
Enumerating objects: 15, done.
Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 967 bytes | 483.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 4 local objects.
remote: fatal error in commit_refs
To https://github.com/andyforprez/exebot.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (failure)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/andyforprez/exebot.git'
```

And it didn't push that file to the repository, even though in VSCode the `M` sign disappeared as if it did push.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution, but some kind of support, as I'm having the same issue, and starting from today too!

Comment: https://www.githubstatus.com/ reports that GitHub is having some problems at the moment.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Good to know it's just a server-side problem

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: All of the victims are gathering here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341960/how-do-i-fix-remote-fatal-error-in-commit-refs-errors-trying-to-push-with-git

Comment: same issue too.

Comment: Thanks to DuckDuckGo, sent me here directly (when searched `! [remote rejected] main -> main (failure)` ) saving a lot of trouble and stress.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Github is down. Just check https://www.githubstatus.com/

Apparently it happens every now and then.

Answer (score 15):

Seems like github is down, check this [website](https://www.githubstatus.com) for github status update

Comment: it was the issue in my scenario.

Answer (score 5):

github is down currently they also mention on their twitter account

[image]

also you can check the status here : https://www.githubstatus.com/

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you can push again. At least i just managed twice in a row